# Mock node js Controller function - getSubscriber which calling to service

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have developed the node js code as MVC architecture. The folder structure is Controller --> service -> model. And I have tried to write unit testing for the following code. Unfortunately, I couldn't mock the service function. So please help me to resolve it.

**Controller**

```
const SubscriberService = require('../../services/subscriber/subscriberService')
const response = require("../../config/response");
const constant = require('../../config/constant');
const SubscriberAnswerService = require('../../services/subscriberAnswer/subscriberAnswerService');
const path = require('path');

class SubscriberController {

    constructor() {
        this.subscriberService = new SubscriberService();
        this.subscriberAnswerService = new SubscriberAnswerService();
    }

    async getSubscriber(req, res) {
        try {
            var { userId } = req;
            const user = await this.subscriberService.findByUserId(userId);
            if (user != null) {

                res.send(response.res(true, constant.MSG.USER_DETAILS, user))
            } else {

                res.status(404).send(response.res(false, constant.MSG.USER_NOT_FOUND));
            }
        } catch (error) {

            res.status(constant.RESPONSE.INTERNAL_ERROR.CODE)
                .send(response.res(false, error.message))
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
    async findByUserId(id) {

        const user = await Subscriber.findOne({ where: { id: id, status: 1 } });

        return user;
    }
```

**Unit Testing Code**

```
describe("Test SubscriberController", () => {
    it("Test getsubscriber", async () => {
        req.userId = 1;
        jest.spyOn(subscriberService, "findByUserId").mockReturnValue(subscriberResponse);
        await subscriberController.getSubscriber(req, res);
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(500);
    });

});
```

**Issue:** I have mocked the service function which `findByUserId` but it does not work. It is given the following error.
`error TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined`

**Please give the solution to mock `findByUserId` function.**

**Subscriber.Controller.test.js**

```
const subscriberModel = require("../src/models/subscriber/subscriberModel");
const SubscriberService = require("../src/services/subscriber/subscriberService");
const SubscriberController = require("../src/controllers/Subscriber/subscriberController");
const subscriberController = new SubscriberController();
const subscriberService = new SubscriberService();
const httpMocks = require("node-mocks-http");

jest.mock("../src/models/subscriber/subscriberModel");

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    req = httpMocks.createRequest();
    res = httpMocks.createResponse();
    next = jest.fn();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    subscriberModel.findOne = jest.fn();
});
// subscriberService.findByUserId = jest.fn();
const subscriberResponse = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Sandun',
    msisdn: '94704377575',
    otp: '1234',
    deleted: 0,
    attempts: 0,
    img_url: 'https://'
}
jest.mock('../src/models/subscriber/subscriberModel', () => () => {
  const SequelizeMock = require("sequelize-mock");
  let dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
  let subscriberMock = dbMock.define('subscribers',  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Sandun',
    msisdn: '94704377575',
    otp: '1234',
    deleted: 0,
    attempts: 0,
    img_url: 'https://'
  });
  let groupMock = dbMock.define('winner', {});
  subscriberMock.belongsTo(groupMock);
  subscriberMock.hasMany();
});

// This test shows how the constructor can be mocked, and how to spy on passed parameters.
describe("Test SubscriberController", () => {
    it("Test getsubscriber", async () => {
        req.userId = 1;
        jest.spyOn(subscriberService, "findByUserId").mockReturnValue(subscriberResponse);
        await subscriberController.getSubscriber(req, res);
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where did you defined subscriberService? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Comment: @EstusFlask I have added the test file content in the post(Subscriber.Controller.test.js) please check it

Comment: `subscriberService` in the test is not the same object as in the controller. Mock the method either on `subscriberController.subscriberService` or `SubscriberService.prototype`.

Comment: @EstusFlask How we can do it..could you please help me

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks a lot. It has worked for ```SubscriberService.prototype```. why we are using ```prototype``` could you please explain it

Comment: Because `findByUserId` is prototype method, at least it seems to according to what you showed, `SubscriberService.prototype.findByUserId === subscriberService.findByUserId`